# I need to write a set of infinities elements and only one point of accumulation.

Tags: real-analysis

And also I need to write a set unbounded that has only one point of accumulation and all others isolated point. I know that the set of numbers naturals has infinite points but don't have any point of accumulation, but I don't know which is those sets of the question.
I have like the definition of point accumulation :

**For the set X ⊆ R, the neighborhood of a  Vε (a)  ∩X-{a}  ≠ ∅, ε > 0 is the variation of neighborhood**

Comment: You want a set of real numbers with exactly one accumulation point?  Can you think of a decreasing set of real numbers that converges to $0$, say?

Comment: Do you have the definition of "accumulation point"?

Comment: So, I can write something like this: 0 < = x < 1 ??

Comment: For the set X ⊆ R, the neighborhood of a  Vε (a)  ∩X-{a}  ≠ ∅

**ε > 0, is the variation of neighborhood **

Comment: The English term is "isolated point", not "insulated point". Because somebody  many years ago said so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any convergent sequence form a set with only a point of accumulation so you can take for exemple
$ A = \{ \frac{1}{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N} \} $

and an unbounded set with the same property is $ A \cup \mathbb{N} $

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!